# NEO4J DATA MODEL Detailing

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

A product catalog has articles. Every article has specific properties. These properties like material, size, form etc. are shared by some of the articles e.g. a tool is available in 3 sizes (6", 8", 10") and 2 materials (304, 316). In a catalog you'll find now 6 records, for every version of the possible combination one. This will raise very fast when you add another property, e.g. Voltage (230, 400, 500) as you now have 18 records. 
I am pondering if I should keep the properties in the nodes so that I have 18 nodes for every property like

```
(n:Tool {name:"X", voltage:"230", size:"6"})
```

and search the nodes for properties to find the right node or if I would try to set those key properties as nodes and connect the tool nodes to the property nodes, e.g.

```
(n:Tool {name:"X"}) -[:HAS_SIZE]- (s:Size {size:"6"})
(n) -[:HAS_VOLTAGE]- (v:Voltage {voltage:"230"}) a.s.o.
```

and try to find the node X by following paths. This last options might also have the charme that I could fill form fields with all available options by picking e.g. all voltage-nodes.

The last might lead to many nodes and relations and when the number raises e.g. having 20 property nodes I am unsure how to find my node X? The query then might look like

```
MATCH (n:Tool) -[:HAS_SIZE]- (s:Size)
MATCH (n:Tool) -[:HAS_VOLTAGE]- (v:Voltage)
MATCH (n:Tool) -[:MADE_OF]- (m:Material)
where s.size = "6" AND v.voltage="230" AND m.material ="304"
return n
```

This will become very big queries.

Maybe someone has a link to an article/post where a basic layout for such a data model is shown? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could browse through these slides https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/neo4j/graphtour-neo4j-murrelektronik. It shows that you can go a lot further, like in modelling your property values as nodes, including support for properties that are calculated on the basis of others, multi-language support and conversion between units. Disclosure : we were part of this project and contributed heavily to the modeling. We also provided the UI.

Comment: Wow, excellent work and so helpful - I see you go much further in the concept and its brilliant. The solution is perfect to have all the different attributes and properties in a useful way and to link each product to those - in the end, a product has then lots of links to every possible attribute, and you get data security on forms as you allow only a list of fitting properties. Is there a chance you post me one query on how to find one of these products to understand how you use the paths to get to this single object? That would be great - thank you!